# Fetch and json in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, fetch

So fetch returns JSON and we can use `.json()` to extract the content as a promise. Let's say my promise is a variable named `PR`. How can I then extract the content of the promise and in which object should I save this? Saying that the fetch brought us a line in a table that had age, name, job. I want to save those in a class object.

Comment: Can you add some code that you have tried and detail exactly what isn't working for you.

Comment: I would suggest using [HttpClient](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#http-request-example) in which you can provide class as type and it maps your object by default

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http-request-data-from-server